# Is there a permutation on $\mathbb{N}$ that, if repeated often enough, eventually shuffles the whole set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, permutations, computability

Does there exist a computable $\pi : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, bijective<sup>†</sup> and such that for all $i,j\in\mathbb{N}$ there is a $k\in\mathbb{N}$ with
$$
  \pi^k(i) > j,
$$
and, if yes, what is a natural example?

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>I'm reasonably sure that at least the inverse will have to be uncomputable, but I would need only $\pi$ itself to be computable.</sub>

Comment: Let $\pi (n)=n+2$ if $n $ is even, $\pi (1)=0$, and otherwise $\pi (n)=n-2$.

Comment: Wow, that's embarrassingly simple.

Comment: by the way, if a bijection is computable, so is its inverse.

Comment: Interesting, could you give some keyword for where to read up on that?

Comment: Any decent introduction to computability (recursion theory) should cover this. A quick algorithm: to compute $\pi^{-1}(n) $, compute in succession  $\pi (0),\pi (1),\dots $, until for some $k $, $\pi (k)=n $, in which case $\pi^{-1}(n)=k $.

Comment: Ok, again, that's _pretty_ obvious in case of $\mathbb{N}$! I need to recall how to keep intuitions about computability and _efficient_ computability apart.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo could you expand your comment to an answer, so that the question can be closed? :-)

Comment: @JossevanDobbendeBruyn Done.

Comment: Hah! a fun question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple example is the permutation $\pi$ given by $\pi(n)=n+2$ if $n$ is even, $\pi(1)=0$, and otherwise $\pi(n)=n−2$. It should be clear that $\pi$ is computable and has the desired property.

By the way, regarding the footnote: if a bijection is computable, so is its inverse, so $\pi^{-1}$ is computable as well. In general, given a computable bijection $\sigma$, a simple algorithm to compute $\sigma^{−1}$ is as follows: Given $n$, to compute $\sigma^{-1}(n)$, compute in succession $\sigma(0),\sigma(1),\dots$, until you reach a $k$ such that $\sigma(k)=n$, which must happen since $\sigma$ is a bijection. This tells us that $\sigma^{−1}(n)=k$.